# Docker "Get Started(Python)" not working

Tags: python, docker

Python developer: See last part "For Python developer"!

MacOs: `10.13.1 (17B1003)`

Docker version:

```
Client:
 Version:      17.09.0-ce
 API version:  1.32
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   afdb6d4
 Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:40:09 2017
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.09.0-ce
 API version:  1.32 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   afdb6d4
 Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:45:38 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

The following "Get stated" is not working:
https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#run-the-app

Running: `docker run -p 4000:80 friendlyhello`

Just produces the following:

```
5e4d9c813323        friendlyhello       "python app.py"     6 seconds ago       Exited (0) 4 seconds ago                       focused_payne
```

And `docker logs` js empty.

Also if:

```
docker run -it -p 4000:80 friendlyhello /bin/bash
```

and `run: python app.py`

Nothing. So it might have to do with `python app.py`.

Note: I am not a Python dev.

#### For Python developer:

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from redis import Redis, RedisError
import os
import socket

# Connect to Redis
redis = Redis(host="redis", db=0, socket_connect_timeout=2, socket_timeout=2)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    try:
        visits = redis.incr("counter")
    except RedisError:
        visits = "<i>cannot connect to Redis, counter disabled</i>"

    html = "<h3>Hello {name}!</h3>" \
           "<b>Hostname:</b> {hostname}<br/>" \
           "<b>Visits:</b> {visits}"
    return html.format(name=os.getenv("NAME", "world"), hostname=socket.gethostname(), visits=visits)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

Comment: `docker logs 5e4d9c813323` is empty?

Comment: Right, nothing in the logs.

Comment: The image build was succesful and you're able to run the container with bash and you see the app.py file in the /app folder? Only the python app.py isn't doing anything?

Comment: can you show your dockerfile

Comment: I just use the one from the docker "Get started".

Answer (score 1):

I think you're doing something else wrong, i copied all three files and ran it just fine.

https://gist.github.com/kingbuzzman/b48be91757fc60e97f6a9a189d006bd8

here are the full steps: (i really suggest you are in `/tmp` when you run this)

```
# 1. Create a temp folder
# 2. Download all the files into the temp folder
# 3. Build the docker image
# 4. Run the image in a detached mode -- so we can curl the url
# 5. Sleep a little and wait until the app is fully up
# 6. Test that it all works
# 7. Stop the container (and we don't care about its stdout)
mkdir -p dockerapp && \
curl -sL https://gist.github.com/kingbuzzman/b48be91757fc60e97f6a9a189d006bd8/download | tar -xvz -C dockerapp --strip-components=1 && \
docker build -t friendlyhello dockerapp && \
docker run --rm -p 4000:80 --name friendlyhello -d friendlyhello && \
sleep 2 && \
curl -s http://localhost:4000/ -w "\n" && \
docker kill friendlyhello >/dev/null
```

(you can highlight and copy all this straight into your terminal and see this)

[image]

What we're looking for here is the last line `<h3>Hello World!</h3><b>Hostname:</b> 979c5e755f64<br/><b>Visits:</b> <i>cannot connect to Redis, counter disabled</i>` which is how we know its running.